# ModelAndView not returning a result to ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, model-view-controller

I am trying to load a static page inside WEB-INF from my controller but it seems that ModelAndView does not work properly,

this is my jquery code:

```
function doAjaxPost() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "${home}loadLogPage",
            success: function(response) {
                alert("success");
                //$("#chatbox").html( response );
            },
            error:function(e){
                console.log("error: ",e);
            }
        });
    }
    setInterval(doAjaxPost, 2500);
```

and this is the function of the controller I am trying to get the result from. Any help would be great.

```
@RequestMapping( method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/loadLogPage" )
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView getSubView( Model model ) {
    System.out.println("access loading page");
   return new ModelAndView( "chatBot/log.html" );
}
```

Comment: What does this mean exactly? _does not work properly_ What doesn't work?

Comment: I can access the method of the controller getSubView via the link /loadLogPage since it shows the msg System.out.println("access loading page"); however in the console log it tells me that the resource ..../loadLogPage is not found and by consequence it does not return any result

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
url: "${home}loadLogPage",
```

is the issue. You've attempted to use template literal syntax but have used it incorrectly. Replace the double quotes with back ticks:

```
url: `${home}loadLogPage`,
```

This assumes the `home` is a variable available to this method.

Comment: tried to remove ${home}, the link to resource is correct but I keep receiving the same error

Comment: Please hard code the same URL that DOES work. Once that works, post the URL here.

Comment: I found the error, the return of the modelandview must be without the extension .html

Comment: Great. Glad you got it sorted out.